# How to implement a lazy loaded list of images in a listview

Tags: android, image, listview, scroll, universal-image-loader

What i am trying to do is toscroll through a list of images. But when i scroll down or up quickly the images are misplaced in order. A diff pic comes in the place where it was supposed to be. I have tried setting the imageview to null drawable from my imageloader library to clear any rpevious images if any. But the issue persists. What should i do

Comment: I'm fairly sure you making a mistake in your adapter. Since not all of us are mind readers, you can start by posting some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally discovered the culprit. I was using the imageview.bringtofront() function which was causing the problem for some unknown reason. I wanted to put a part of the imageview infront of the other and was using the relative layout & bring to front. Now i removed the bringtofront() and rearranged the imageview in relativelayout so that its already in the front. Resolved. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You can try  to use [Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

This is for listView optimization and improving performance if your listView contain images from web.

Features:

- Multithread image loading Possibility of wide tuning ImageLoader's
- configuration (thread executors, downlaoder, decoder, memory and disc
- cache, display image options, and others) Possibility of image
- caching in memory and/or on device's file sysytem (or SD card)
- Possibility to "listen" loading process Possibility to customize
  every display image call with separated options Widget support